# Pandas convert data type from object to float

Tags: python, pandas

I read some weather data from a `.csv` file as a dataframe named "weather". The problem is that the data type of one of the columns is `object`. This is weird, as it indicates temperature. How do I change it to having a `float` data type? I tried `to_numeric`, but it can't parse it.

```
weather.info()
weather.head()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 304 entries, 2017-01-01 to 2017-10-31
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Temp    304 non-null object
Rain    304 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 17.1+ KB

           Temp     Rain
Date        
2017-01-01  12.4    0.0
2017-02-01  11      0.6
2017-03-01  10.4    0.6
2017-04-01  10.9    0.2
2017-05-01  13.2    0.0
```

Comment: I think it might pay off to look why this is an object. Is there anything unusual for that column?

Comment: I'd suggest to add the `pandas` flag and add it to the description as it is not about plain Python.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that's the first thing I did! It's a simple csv file. The numbers look no different than the rain column which was just fine...

Answer (score 53):

#### 1. Using pandas.Series.astype

- You can use `pandas.Series.astype`
- You can do something like this :

  ```
    weather["Temp"] = weather.Temp.astype(float)
  ```

#### 2. Using pd.to_numeric

- You can also use `pd.to_numeric` that will convert the column from object to float
- For details on how to use it checkout this link :http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html
- Example :

  ```
    s = pd.Series(['apple', '1.0', '2', -3])
    print(pd.to_numeric(s, errors='ignore'))
    print("=========================")
    print(pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce'))
  ```
- Output:

  ```
    0    apple
    1      1.0
    2        2
    3       -3
    =========================
    dtype: object
    0    NaN
    1    1.0
    2    2.0
    3   -3.0
    dtype: float64
  ```
- In your case you can do something like this:

  ```
    weather["Temp"] = pd.to_numeric(weather.Temp, errors='coerce')
  ```

#### 3. Using convert_objects

- Other option is to use `convert_objects`
- Example is as follows

  ```
    >> pd.Series([1,2,3,4,'.']).convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

    0     1
    1     2
    2     3
    3     4
    4   NaN
    dtype: float64
  ```
- You can use this as follows:

  ```
    weather["Temp"] = weather.Temp.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
  ```
- I have showed you examples because if any of your column won't have a number then it will be converted to `NaN`... so be careful while using it.

Answer (score 11):

I tried all methods suggested here but sadly none worked. Instead, found this to be working:

```
df['column'] = pd.to_numeric(df['column'],errors = 'coerce')
```

And then check it using:

```
print(df.info())
```

Answer (score 5):

I eventually used:

```
weather["Temp"] = weather["Temp"].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

It worked just fine, except that I got the following message.

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:3: FutureWarning:
convert_objects is deprecated.  Use the data-type specific converters pd.to_datetime, pd.to_timedelta and pd.to_numeric.
```

Comment: hmm, why do use it? need `weather["Temp"] = pd.to_numeric(weather.Temp, errors='coerce')`

Comment: Yeah thanks! worked perfectly. What's the explanation?

Comment: WARNING: convert_objects is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].map(lambda x: float(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

First check your data cuz you may get an error if you have ',' instead of '.'
if so, you need to transform every ',' into '.' with a function :

```
def replacee(s):
i=str(s).find(',')
if(i>0):
    return s[:i] + '.' + s[i+1:]
else :
    return s
```

then you need to apply this function on every row in your column :

```
dfOPA['Montant']=dfOPA['Montant'].apply(replacee)
```

then the convert function will work fine :

```
dfOPA['Montant'] = pd.to_numeric(dfOPA['Montant'],errors = 'coerce')
```

Answer (score -2):

Eg, For Converting $40,000.00 `object` **to** 40000 `int` or `float`32

**Follow this step by step :**

```
$40,000.00 ---(**1**. remove $)--->  40,000.00  ---(**2**. remove , comma)--->  40000.00 ---(**3**. remove . dot)--->  4000000  ---(**4**. remove empty space)---> 4000000  ---(**5**. Remove NA Values)--->  4000000 ---(**6**. now this is object type so, convert to int using .astype(int) )---> 4000000  ---(**7**. divide by 100)---> 40000
```

**Implementing code In Pandas**

```
table1["Price"] = table1["Price"].str.replace('$','')<br>
table1["Price"] = table1["Price"].str.replace(',','')<br>
table1["Price"] = table1["Price"].str.replace('.','')<br>
table1["Price"] = table1["Price"].str.replace(' ','')     
table1 = table1.dropna()<br>
table1["Price"] = table1["Price"].astype(int)<br>
table1["Price"] = table1["Price"] / 100<br>
```

Finally it's done

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).