# Python - How to convert from object to float

Tags: python, pandas

I had an XLSX file with 2 columns namely `months` and `revenue` and saved it as a CSV file. By using pandas to read my csv file, the `revenue` column has now turned into object.  How can I change this column to float?

```
data = pd.DataFrame

dat['revenue']

7980.79
Nan
1000.25
17800.85
.....
Nan 
2457.85
6789.33
```

This is the column I want to change but it has been given me different errors

I tried,  `astype`, `to_numeric` but no success.

Some of the errors I got is:

> Cannot parse a string '798.79'

Comment: Welcome, Does this what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48094854/python-convert-object-to-float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now using nucsit026's answer to create a slightly different dataFrame with strings

```
dic = {'revenue':['7980.79',np.nan,'1000.25','17800.85','None','2457.85','6789.33']}
print(df)
print(df['revenue'].dtypes
```

Output:

```
    revenue
0   7980.79
1   NaN
2   1000.25
3   17800.85
4   None
5   2457.85
6   6789.33

dtype('O')
```

try this:

```
df['revenue']=pd.to_numeric(data['revenue'], errors='coerce').fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

it will replace `nan` with 0s

Output:

```
0     7980.79
1        0.00
2     1000.25
3    17800.85
4        0.00
5     2457.85
6     6789.33
Name: revenue, dtype: float64
```

**EDIT**:

From your shared error if quotes are the problem you can use

```
df['revenue']=df['revenue'].str.strip("'")
```

and then try to convert to float using above mentioned code

**EDIT2**

OP had some spaces in the column values like this

```
Month  Revenue
Apr-13 16 004 258.24
May-13
Jun-13 16 469 157.71
Jul-13 19 054 861.01
Aug-13 20 021 803.71
Sep-13 21 285 537.45
Oct-13 22 193 453.80
Nov-13 21 862 298.20
Dec-13 10 053 557.64
Jan-14 17 358 063.34
Feb-14 19 469 161.04
Mar-14 22 567 078.21
Apr-14 20 401 188.64
```

In this case use following code:

```
df['revenue']=df['revenue'].replace(' ', '', regex=True)
```

and then perform the conversion

Comment: I tried your code and my revenue list has all 0s. What happened to my numbers and how do I take it from there?

Comment: whats the output if you remove `fillna` part

Comment: Without fillna part, everything is now NaN

Comment: whats your data looks like, i have tried your given data and it worked fine for me can you share some of the data set in original form

Comment: I am fairly new on this platform and i am not quite sure how to attach the file. The file is on my PC

Comment: updated my answer please check especially for special characters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206638/discussion-between-john-mutesi-and-m-s-n).

Answer (score 0):

From above link:

```
dic = {'revenue':[7980.79,None,1000.25,17800.85,None,2457.85,6789.33]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
df['revenue'] = df.revenue.astype(float)
df
```

output

```
    revenue
0   7980.79
1   NaN
2   1000.25
3   17800.85
4   NaN
5   2457.85
6   6789.33
```

Comment: This is perfect and it worked. However,  my revenue column has 3730 values. How will my dic look like? Should use a for loop and then append?

Comment: Using `df['revenue'] = df.revenue.astype(float)` means converting column's values _(3730 )_ to float, I used dic as example for explanation. You don't need to use it.