# Convert Object into Float or String in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I have a DataFrame/CSV file that I've wrangled and I'm now using Seaborn to make certain plots. [image: This is how it looks with the head and it's info]

What I want to do is to convert the "time" column from an OBJECT to a String or a number or a float64 so that I can plot it against the "MW" column which is a float64. The error that I get using Seaborn is

"float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'"

How do I do that? I have tried many methods including the ones displayed over here: [Python convert object to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48094854/python-convert-object-to-float)
but no luck, unfortunately.

EDIT:
Here's some sample data:

```
    MW  date    time    Month   Year    Week    Day
0   0.5814  2013-09-01  01:00:00    9   2013    35  Sunday
1   0.5814  2013-09-01  02:00:00    9   2013    35  Sunday
2   0.5814  2013-09-01  03:00:00    9   2013    35  Sunday
3   0.5814  2013-09-01  04:00:00    9   2013    35  Sunday
4   0.5814  2013-09-01  05:00:00    9   2013    35  Sunday
```

Comment: `Aberdeen['date']=pd.to_datetime(Aberdeen['date'])` Use this to convert from string to date and time, then convert to numeric using the referenced method.

Comment: @r-beginners I'm getting an error that says <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime
And it's not the date that I want, it's the time.

Comment: Please provide sample data if possible.

Comment: @r-beginners Posted

Comment: `Aberdeen['time'] = Aberdeen['time'].dt.hour`Using this, you can convert the time column to a numeric value of time.

Comment: @r-beginners I'm getting an error saying "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values" even though it is a datetime.time value

Comment: `import pandas as pd;Aberdeen['time']=pd.to_datetime(Aberdeen['time'])` Run this first.

Comment: @r-beginners it still doesn't work

Comment: for some odd reason, idk why its working on collabs but not on the notebook. @r-beginners

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your explanation; I'll delete before my comment. I'm afraid there is nothing more I can do for you.

Comment: How do you use seaborn to plot?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Input this code in before making the plot.
pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()

Afterwards, I was using seaborn as
sns.lineplot(x=Aberdeen['time'], y=Aberdeen['MW'],data=Aberdeen)

And it worked :)